# "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion" when using blocks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks

i´m getting these warnings for my code below.
Any ideas how to fix that?
Thanks for any help.

- Type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'
- Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'void *';
- Unused variable 'mymoviePlayerController'

The important line is the `"__block mymoviePlayerController = nil;`

```
- (void) moviePlaybackCompleteLightBox:(NSNotification*) notification {

        MPMoviePlayerController *mymoviePlayerController = [notification object];  
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self  
                                                        name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                                      object:mymoviePlayerController]; 


        // movie fadein transition ====================
        self.moviePlayerController.view.alpha = 1;

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                         animations:^{
                             self.moviePlayerController.view.alpha = 0;   
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) { 
                             [mymoviePlayerController stop];
                             [mymoviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
                             __block mymoviePlayerController = nil;

                         }];

    }
```

Comment: have you declared "mymoviePlayerController" in your .h file also?? i mean both locally and globally??

Comment: Also specify the line where you are getting the first and second warning

Comment: "The important line is the "__block mymoviePlayerController = nil;" This throws the warning.

Comment: If you are using ARC then you do not need to write this line. [removefromSuperview] does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't have to set the `mymoviePlayerController` variable to nil, if you don' use it afterwards. Just don't worry about it, removing the controller's view from its superview is enough.

Second, you can't make a variable writable using the `__block` qualifier inside of a block. You'll have to modify your code to make the variable writable outside of the block:

```
__block MPMoviePlayerController *blockMoviePlayerController = mymoviePlayerController;
[UIView animate...animations:...complection:^(BOOL finished) {
    blockMoviePlayerController = nil; // or something else
}];
```

Comment: Thanks to Vladimir and Fabian for their help. Good to know. It fixes the problem. Thanks for your fast reply. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 5):

`__block` is used when you **declare** variable, not when you assign value to it. So compiler treats the following line as variable declaration, which is wrong:

```
 __block mymoviePlayerController = nil;
```

You should use __block attribute when declare variable:

```
__block MPMoviePlayerController *mymoviePlayerController = [notification object];
```

**P.S.** Why do you use __block here anyway? It looks you don't need it in this situation